# Infinispan embedded cache mode - Parallel execution Fails - concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, infinispan

I'm running Infinispan in the embedded mode using the map reduce framework in one of my batch application. If the 2 clients invoke the batch at same time, this parallel execution causes following exception:

> 2013-07-08 11:54:40,346 ERROR [main]
>   []:[AbstractStep]:[] Encountered an error
>   executing the step org.infinispan.CacheException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.infinispan.CacheException: org.infinispan.CacheException: Could
>   not move intermediate keys/values for M/R task
>   f1e249c2-bc87-41e9-9c8d-985b4c2c1ba8
>           at org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.MapReduceTask.execute(MapReduceTask.java:339)
>   ~[infinispan-core-5.2.5.Final.jar:5.2.5.Final]
>           at org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.MapReduceTask.execute(MapReduceTask.java:619)
>   ~[infinispan-core-5.2.5.Final.jar:5.2.5.Final]
>           at com.jpmorgan.ct.lri.lcr.rpt.distexec.node.MasterNode.run(MasterNode.java:49)

Comment: Only a very quick note: Once you found a bugzilla for it, it's a known problem. I would suggest you to wait for developers to repair it. Or maybe you should provide more specific information like: which versions do you use etc. to let others know whether this is really related to aforementioned bugzilla or not.

Comment: Tsykora, we don't really use bugzilla for tracking Infinispan bugs but rather JIRA (https://jira.jboss.org/browse/ISPN). We had a similar issue before but should be fixed in 5.2 already. Can you provide a test case to replicate the issue? Can you also try with the latest final release: 5.3.0.Final?

Comment: Galder, i will try with 5.3.0, but the current runtime is 5.2.5. Test case, batch application which uses infinispan MR framework and works with distributed cache and uses UDP as protocol. if the 2 request comes for the batch application, suppose if one request starts the MR and other request starts pouring the records in Dist cache, at that time we are seeing the above exception. Both requests use same config files and same dist named cache.

Comment: Galder, Even i tried with 5.3.0 version, issue still persist. As a work around I fixed using changing the UDP port number between the request. Now each request will get the Separate UDP port number, and the whole functionality works good.